# How to Typeset the Following Diagram (Using any package)

Tags: typography

I am in the process of typesetting some old typewriter written notes.

The below diagram illustrates a certain principle in Marxian Economics.

I do not know how to approach this problem. - I am not sure how to achieve the vertical alignments. (Each of the blocks of text describe the character above it). Then a horizontal curly bracket should wrap around the text describing the elements of C and V and be labelled with "Input" as shown.

[image: Diagram to be typeset]

```
\begin{align*} 
 GDP = C & + V & + S \\ 
 \text{Output:} &  \underbrace{\text{Constant capital i.e. depreciation on machinery and raw material}  \text{Variable capital i.e. wages}_{\text{Input}}}  & \text{Surplus}
    \end{align*}
```

Which is not the desired results. 
So my specific question remains, what set of alterations should I use to achieve the desired results

Comment: This is a do-it-for-me question. Please post what you have so far and ask a specific question.

Comment: \begin{align*} 
GDP = C & + V & + S \\ 
\text{Output:} &  \underbrace{\text{Constant capital i.e. depreciation on machinery and raw material}  \text{Variable capital i.e. wages}_{\text{Input}}}  & \text{Surplus}
\end{align*}

Which is not the desired results. 
So my specific question remains, what set of alterations should I use to achieve the desired results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\auxarray}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$#1$}\\#2
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\auxarray{}{Output}
\quad
\auxarray{\mathit{GNP}}{}
=
{\underbrace{
  \auxarray{C}{Constant capital\\i.e.\ depreciation\\on machinery and\\raw material}
  +
  \auxarray{V}{Variable\\capital\\i.e.\\wages}
 }_{\textstyle\text{Input}}}
+
\auxarray{S}{Surplus}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the definition of `\auxarray` into

```
\newcommand{\auxarray}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$#1$}\\#2
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a relatively new LaTex user, I found it easy to follow and informative and advancing of my knowledge of LaTex

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with a `tabular` environment and `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{center}\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
     GNP ${}={} $ & \Rnode{C}{C} & \Rnode{V}{V} & \Rnode{S}{S} \\[3ex]
     Output & \pnode(-2pt,-9ex){A}\eqmakebox[B]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Constant capital \\ i.e. depreciation \\on machinery \\ and raw materials
     \end{tabular}} %
     &\eqmakebox[B]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Variable capital \\ i.e. wages
     \end{tabular}} \pnode(2pt,-9ex){B} & \eqmakebox[B]{Surplus} \\
   \end{tabular}
\ncbar[arm=1ex, angle=-90]{A}{B}\nbput{Input}
\psset{linestyle =none}
\ncline{C}{V}\ncput*{ + }
\ncline{V}{S}\ncput*{ + }
\end{center}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]